# Does anyone know of any alternatives to recuva for file recovery?

Tags: files, data-recovery

I was using recuva to find pictures and videos on a windows xp hard drive, but I keep getting an internal error message. Does anyone know of an alternative program for recovering broken and damaged files?

I know that with ubuntu it's sometimes better and I had some more success recovering data from windows computers with ubuntu, I tried `find` but are there any GUI programs that someone would recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Testdisk:**

TestDisk is a good Open Source data recovery software. It is in the main Ubuntu Repository.

[image: Install via the software center]

**Or:**

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

[image]